# Access to install.php on existing installation

Tags: 7, distributions

I've created an installation profile.
Once the site is created and I return to install.php I can restart the installation profile. How can the install.php file be blocked so that the Drupal already installed message is shown?
When the standard profile is used 3 variables are set in the variable table:

```
install_profile     s:8:"standard";
install_task     s:4:"done";
install_time     i:1323783143;
```

When I look at the variables table after I run my custom installation profile only one variable is set as:

```
install_task    s:23:"install_profile_modules";
```

What's the correct way to set these variables?

Comment: These variables are set automatically for all of my custom profiles (both Drupal 6 and 7) so I would suggest your profile is doing something to end the process prematurely. The fact that the last `install_task` run was `install_profile_modules` supports this...the installation essentially 'failed' (whether it informed you of that or not) either during or immediately after that task was run

Comment: Seems like you're right! The installation profile itself returns no errors and no specific information in the logfiles. Only a notice: Notice: Undefined index: distribution_name in drupal_install_profile_distribution_name() (line 202 of /usr/local/websites/drupal7/includes/install.inc). which has to be part of the problem and occurs because the status of the record with name 'standard' is set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a module that's enabled with the installation profile using the drupal_goto function on hook_user_login.

This function ends the request, therefore the profile doesn't go to the page showing 'Visit your new site'.
It goes to the URL provided in drupal_goto instead and variables are not set because the function install_finished() was never called.